# PHP to call original XML file when XSL form data submitted

Tags: php, xml, forms, xslt, request

I have a page that uses an XML file matched with an XSL stylesheet to create a form.

The XML file is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="XSL/BasicForm.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<xml>
<title></title>
<entry1></entry1>
<enrty2></entry2>
<entry3></entry3>
</xml>
```

And the BasicForm.xsl file which it references to create the form is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="xml">

<form method="POST" action="action.php">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <label>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>: 
                <input name="{name()}" type="text" />
            </label>
            <br />
</xsl:for-each>  

<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitButton"/>
<br/>

</form>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, upon submitting the form, a PHP file is referenced for form processing and printing.  The PHP file looks like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body >

<?php

$myFile = ;

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);

$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($theData, LIBXML_NOERROR);
if ($doc !== FALSE) {
$text = ''; // used to accumulate output while walking XML tree
foreach ($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $child) {
    if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) { // keep text nodes
        $text .= $child->wholeText;
    } else if (array_key_exists($child->tagName, $_POST)) {
        // replace nodes whose tag matches a POST variable
        $text .= $_POST[$child->tagName];
    } else { // keep other nodes
        $text .= $doc->saveXML($child);
    }
}
echo $text . "\n";
} else {
echo "Failed to parse XML\n";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

What I need to do is call upon the original XML file and match it to the $myFile variable in order to process it with the form's submitted data.  I can't just put the absolute reference in the variable field because multiple files will be used with this process (depending on what file the user clicks on).  So again, I need to find a way to call upon the original XML file within the PHP script when the XSL form is submitted.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
E

Comment: I also realize that it could be a problem that the original XML file - even if successfully referenced from PHP - continually references the XSL file, perhaps causing an inability to be parsed correctly. I dunno, though.

Comment: @user633264: This falls out of scope for general XSLT question. It's more like a web application design question...

Comment: @user633264: Your application knows wich XML document sends the first time. If there are many of those you need to add some reference in the XML document itself (an URL query string, a hash key, etc.). Then the transformation adds this identifier to the form (maybe as hidden field). That way, the handler for the POST request recive the edited data of the form and the original one through the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly following where you're "losing" the contents of the original XML file.  You could always url_encode the contents of the xml file and include it as a hidden variable in the form being presented to the end user.   This might not be possible if the xml files are particularly large but in this example with only 4 values you could just pass the XML as a post field and decode it in action.php

Comment: I'm not "loosing" the contents, I just don't know how to reference the XML file path in PHP and match it to the appropriate variable.  I've tried to do a $POST method, but it didn't work.  I'm not sure if I coded it right, or if the XML could not be parsed because of it's initial reference to the stylesheet.  Any clues on how to do this proper would be great.  If I encoded the contents in the XSL, I'd probably have to change the PHP parsing method completely.  Thank you for the input.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you're posting the XML originally? You should be able to do the $POST method by A) Storing the XML as a text string, B) urlencode($string), C) <input type="hidden" name="originalXML" value="<?=$string?>".  Which part of that is breaking?

Comment: Ok, so, Ogre...here's a preview of the page:  http://www.sciencefictionjournal.com/Plaza/Rad.php
It's going to be a Madlib page.  If you fill out the form, everything works fine because I have the file url directly linked in the $myFile variable of the Mad.php file (which is the last code block in the question above).  But what I actually need is to call upon the file name based on what file is clicked on initially.  Does that make sense? 

I like your blog, BTW.

Comment: I think this should be fine... your initial page link includes the post variable for the file as you have listed.  When you post the form itself just do the following: `<input type='hidden' name='originalXML' value='<?=$_POST['file']?>'/>` inside of your form.  You should escape the posted variable, but then when you re-submit the form, you can now just look for the variable called originalXML and it will be the same as your $myFile variable...  Sorry if I'm still not getting it... but with this you SHOULD be able to add a second link and have the file variable populate through

Comment: Thanks very much - sounds like it will work and I'll give it a shot.

Comment: So, this method did not work (because PHP evidently cannot be accessed within a stylsheet), however, I solved the problem.   

    $xp->setParameter();

Can be used to set the original post data to a XSLT parameter before transformation.  That parameter can then be called on as post data when the form is submitted.  

Thanks for the help, Ogre.  You gave me some great leads.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using setParameter() to pass the filepath variable to XSLT process command in PHP just before the transformation.  Then the parameter was called as post data to call the original XML filepath.

E